# How to control and filter warnings in vim-latex?

Tags: filetype-tex

While vim-latex is great, I've been having a bit of trouble using some of its features.
Controlling the warning system (and hotfix window) has been particularly difficult for me. Today I'm trying to figure out how to use the variable [g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-compiling.html#Tex_IgnoredWarnings). I have several questions:

- How is the pattern matching done precisely? What regular expression language is being used, and what string is it matched against? The documentation doesn't say.
- Is there a way to ignore *all* warnings? Perhaps in a way more convenient than, say, writing a pattern which matches all warnings. I tried adding a pattern line with an empty string, not even this worked.
- I'd really like to specifically ignore "Reference ... on page ... undefined ..." warnings.

Here is the current lines of my .vimrc with my attempts to address the last two points above. Nothing at all happened so far:

```
let g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings =
    \''."\n".
    \'Underfull'."\n".
    \'Overfull'."\n".
    \'specifier changed to'."\n".
    \'You have requested'."\n".
    \'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
    \'There were undefined references'."\n".
    \'Citation %.%# undefined'."\n".
    \'Reference %.%# undefined'."\n".
    \'LaTeX Warning: Reference'."\n".
    \'Foreign command %.%#'."\n"
let g:Tex_IgnoreLevel = 11
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You might have some luck asking the plugin developers on github